# Changing Foreign Key Table Name Isn't Updating Data Properly

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE publishers
(
    name        VARCHAR(50)                         NOT NULL,
    status      TINYINT         DEFAULT 1           NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT publishers_pk PRIMARY KEY (name)
); 

CREATE TABLE titles
(
    id          INT                 NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    publisher   VARCHAR(50),
    title       VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    status      ENUM('active', 'announced', 'inactive'),
    discount    TINYINT             NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT title_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT title_fk FOREIGN KEY (publisher)
        REFERENCES publishers (name)
        ON DELETE   SET NULL
        ON UPDATE   CASCADE
);
```

When I change the "name" in publishers, it isn't changing the "publisher" in the titles table. Why is the behavior working this way?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what engine you are using?  I read that MySQL with the default engine will parse the foreign key constraints but not actually do anything with them.  Is it possible you're using the MyISAM engine?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html

Comment: My host does implement the MyISAM engine. Is there a way to change the engine without messing up my data?

Comment: This link actually has some good examples, split up by engine, it appears you CAN accomplish what you want to do, just slightly differently than how you're doing it:  http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html -- triggers.

Comment: As for changing from one engine to another, I'm not sure what it entails as I've never done it, you can search it I was able to find this link:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

Comment: I went through and changed the engine on the tables in my database, but it still isn't enforcing the integrity. Hmm.

Comment: How exactly did you change the engine, via ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=InnoDB ?  I would think you need to drop the tables and recreate them (or create adjacent tables and copy over the data, if you have valuable data in your existing tables).

Comment: OK I will try that and see.